# GCP Bitnami Lamp Stack CPU vs Memory

Tags: memory, google-cloud-platform, cpu-usage, lamp, bitnami

I have implemented a system whereby people can upload files to a LAMP Stack folder/directory in htdocs through http post. Does image upload systems such as this require cpu power more than memory power, or vice versa?

I am asking so I can make a better choice between High CPU or High Memory machine type in Google Cloud Compute Engine Bitnami Lamp Stack.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer requires more details that your question provides. How many simultaneous users? How large are the uploads? What is the average upload speed? What about download traffic? What other tasks is the server performing?

There are several factors to consider. CPU selection which affects network bandwidth; memory size affects caching; storage type and size affect bandwidth and IOPS.

Before getting into specifics, as a general rule once you are at the `n1-standard-1` instance size and larger, memory and disk size is more important than CPU speed. Network data transfer is not a high consumer of CPU cycles until you get into the tens or hundreds of Megabits per second sustained.

**CPU Selection**

Google Compute Engine VM instances limit network speed based upon the instance size. Google provides up to 2 Gbit per second speeds per CPU core. You will only achieve this performance level between two instances in the same zone in the same VPC. The more vCPU cores the higher the possible bandwidth. Instances smaller than `n1-standard-1` have shared vCPUs and have no bandwidth specs.

**Memory Selection**

As a general rule, the more memory you have, the better the performance. However, this depends greatly on your software design. Will you be caching uploads in memory before writing to disk (the usual case)? If so then you will need enough memory to handle the number of simultaneous uploads multiplied by the average size.

**Storage Selection**

The disk I/O performance is directly dependant on the disk type and disk size. Small disks do not have high performance. How much performance do you need? That depends on the questions asked above.

**Summary**

I recommend creating a benchmark that models what you need to obtain. Then select an instance size, memory size, disk type, and disk size. Then run the benchmark. Monitor CPU usage, memory utilization, disk capacity, etc. Then adjust the VM instance to fine-tune those numbers. Remember to always leave extra capacity in each category. Trying to utilize 100% often means hitting a performance knee where everything collapses.